# When I use for loop in JavaScript, Is exist all value in memory?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, memory

As I was studying closures and local variables,
I was curious to see the example below.

```
function myLoop() {
   var result = [], i, n = 4;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       result[i] = function () {
         return i;
       }
   }

  return result;
}

var l = myLoop();
var f = l[0];
console.log(f()); // undefined
```

I recently knew **how variable allocate**.
Point to a value, not a allocate.

if I declare variable,
I allocated 'string'.
and I again allocated another string

```
var str = 'hello';
str = 'world';
```

and

```
str -> hello,  
str -> world
```

Because 'String' is immutable.

***Result***
In conclusion, I wonder what is the status in memory?
i of 'for loop' exist all value in memory?
i -> 0,
i -> 1,
i -> 2,
i -> 3

or

i = 1(..3,4) allocate?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you only have a single binding for `i`, one which is declared at the beginning of `myLoop`. Every array item in `result` has a function which points to that singular `i`. So, when `myLoop` returns, you've created an array of functions, all of which reference a single value, the `i` whose value is `4`:

```js
function myLoop() {
   var result = [], i, n = 4;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       result[i] = function () {
         return i;
       }
   }

  return result;
}

const arr = myLoop();
console.log(
  arr[0](),
  arr[1]()
);
```

This value will eventually be garbage collected (the variable name's link to the value it contains) once nothing can reference the `arr` or any of its functions anymore.

If you had used `let` in the `for` loop instead of `var`, you would have a separate binding for `i` on each iteration:

```js
function myLoop() {
   var result = [], n = 4;

   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       result[i] = function () {
         return i;
       }
   }

  return result;
}

const arr = myLoop();
console.log(
  arr[0](),
  arr[1]()
);
```

in which case, every iteration of the `for` loop would have its own `i` value, so there'd be 4 separate values for `i` in memory at the time `myLoop` returns. Just like above, those 4 values will continue to exist until nothing can reference them anymore, and they get garbage collected.

(Technically, there'd also be *another* temporary binding or two for `i` for the duration of the loop, created by the `for` loop due to the mechanics of `let` loop declarations, but it's near invisible to scripts and is more confusing than useful to think about in this situation)

Comment: Thank you, so above example exist four values(1~4) in memory. 
Is that right?

Comment: That's right - since, as you can see from the snippet, `arr[0]()` produces a different value from `arr[1]()` (so both values are being stored)

Comment: Thank you. That`s very kind of you. You made my day

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Comment: Well.. where is the checkbox? I can`t find it

Comment: It's at the top left of every answer.

Comment: Doesn't say much about memory though... Does the fact there is a single binding really means a single allocation is done? I'm not sure to get exactly what OP is after, in my opinion the question needs a reformulation, but it seems they are interested in the fact `str = "abc"; str+="def"` will create `"abc"`, `"def"` and `"abcdef"` strings and (maybe?) are wondering if the same applies to numbers(?)

Comment: @Kaiido Every variable binding *necessarily* takes some amount of memory, right? 
https://jsfiddle.net/eo0atcwf/ If you remove the `i` parameter, for me, memory usage decreases from ~301M to ~184M. The fewer bindings there are, the fewer items in the LexicalEnvironments there are, so there's less persistent state in the script (and less memory usage), at least until everything gets GC'd

Comment: I'm not a subject-matter expert here, but I doubt all engines will do the same, or even the same engine in two different configurations. Trying to guess how things work under the hood with such cases is near impossible nowadays, optimizers are everywhere and what you write is often far from what CPU receives, and Garbage Collecting has become such a complicated matter that memory management for such small snippet is an obscure science to me. Just pointing out that I fear there is a miscommunication between you and OP.